# Making a Poor Man's Water Injection System

Tags: turbocharger, timing

I was just reading this [article on water injection systems](http://www.autospeed.com/cms/article.html?&title=Water-Injection&A=107970) and they made an interesting comment:

> Note that it has been suggested in some circles that the water can be
>   directly added to the petrol by using a solvent such as acetone.
>   However, I have not heard of anyone actually doing this!

This actually sounds like it might actually work.  IPA, isopropanol, is the main ingredient in HEAT, which is used to remove water from the gas tank, since water is soluble in IPA.  The question would be water ratio of water to IPA would one use and what ratio of fuel to IPA/water?

I've heard that some engines use the knock sensor to dynamically learn how much timing advance can be run on the engine, so theoretically, this could not just help with cleaning the pistons and turbine, but also get you more HP through more advanced timing.

So has anyone ever heard of someone doing this style of DIY water injection on a stock engine?

**EDIT**

According to the article:

> However, testing on aircraft engines indicates that the mass of water
>   required to suppress detonation is 20-30 per cent of the weight of the
>   total liquid charge (that is, the water plus the petrol) being
>   consumed.

Comment: Company selling water injection systems and discussing their benefits:  https://www.aemelectronics.com/products/water-methanol-injection-systems/water-methanol-injection-kit-for-forced-induction-gasoline-engines

Comment: would a nitrous system just be easier...

Comment: @SolarMike maybe, but this is more of a curiosity thing than me trying to accomplish a specific task.

Comment: How much are you prepared to spend?

Comment: @SolarMike poor man's are the key words here...

Comment: Is this motor vehicle maintenance or repair? If this is design then it is surely off topic... As you clearly state "making.."...